# Getting all related objects via related table. Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, ef-fluent-api

I have two tables. Parent table and link table that stores ids. Parent table have related data from itself. Here is Models:

```
public class People
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }   
public List<Relation> Relations { get; set; }
}

public class Relation
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public int ParentPeopleID { get; set; }
public int ChildPeopleID { get; set; }   
public People People { get; set; }
}
```

Some test data[image]
And mapped them like this

```
HasRequired(p => p.People).WithMany(p => p.Relations).HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentPeopleID);
```

When I'm calling

```
var Peoplelist = MyDbContext.People.Include(p=>p.Relations.Select(r=>r.People)).Where(p=>p.Id==1).ToList();
```

It returns itself not related People. In my case it should returns People with ids: 2,3,4 but returns three People with id 1

I can get what I need by MyDbContext.Relation but need by MyDbContext.People

What i'm doing wrong?
Is there another way to do that?

Comment: `Include` is just for eager loading navigation properties, it does not affect the query result. Your sample query should return just one entity with Id 1. Looks like you want to retrieve a list of children of a specific entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivan is correct. You should use join keyword to join the both tables as below. You will get the desired result (People with ids: 2,3,4) by using this query:

```
var Peoplelist = MyDbContext.Peoples.Join(MyDbContext.Relations, p => p.Id, r => r.ChildPeopleID, 
            (p, r) => new {p, r})
            .Where(j => j.r.ParentPeopleID == 1).ToList();
```

Hope this will help.